# Density plot from plotting multiple arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a MxN (say, 1000x50) array. I want to plot each 50-point line onto the same plot, and have a heatmap of their density.

Simply doing a `plt.pcolor(data)` is not what I want, since I don't want to plot the matrix.

This is what I want to plot, but as I said it doesn't provide me with the heatmap I need.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(1000, 50)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(0,1000):
    ax.plot(data[i], '.')

plt.show()
```

I would like a way of getting this together (I assume it will have something to do with histograms and binning?).

EDIT: simply adding an `alpha` value to the plot ( `ax.plot(data[i], '.r', alpha=0.01)`) achieves something similar to what I want. I would like, however, to have a heatmap with different colours.

Comment: i am not sure, as to what exactly you want. Does [this](https://i.imgur.com/aKdIzUn.png) look like something you were going for (i've used a normal distribution instead of uniform)?

Comment: @SamProell that is precisely what I was going for. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already pointed out in your question, probably one of the simplest approaches involves histograms. A linear approximation of the histogram is probably enough for this application.

You can use `np.histogram` to calculate bin heights and edges and use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` to obtain a function that provides an interpolation of the histogram. We can define a simple helper function to get the approximate density around each value in one column of the data array:

```
# import scipy.interpolate as interp
def get_density(vals, bins=30, kind="linear"):
    y, bin_edges = np.histogram(vals, bins=bins, density=True)
    x = (bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])/2.
    f = interp.interp1d(x, y, kind=kind, fill_value="extrapolate")
    return f(vals)
```

Then you can use any [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) you want to map the density to a color value. The easiest way to go from here is to use `plt.scatter` instead of `plot`, where you can provide a specific color for every data point.

I would do something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    colors = plt.cm.viridis(get_density(data[:, i]))
    ax.scatter(i*np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:, i], c=colors, marker='.')
```

Comment: I have been using this now for a while, thanks a lot for this answer. However, lately I have been trying to use a custom-made `LinearSegmentedColormap` as opposed to a `ListedColormap` like viridis, and I am getting a `ValueError: data mapping points must start with x=0 and end with x=1` when I try to compute `colors`. Is there a way to solve this? Or is it another question I need to open?

Comment: @Enzo, I am not familiar with custom colormaps.. It might be best to post a new, more specific, question!